# Seperate background image with repeat x

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, background-image

I am using the Bootstrap rating for my website http://plugins.krajee.com/star-rating .
I am wondering if it is possible to get each of the stars one by one, and make an animation when the page loads. 
So if for example I have 3 stars rating, then when I load the page I what the first star to animate from big to smaller, then the second and then the third etc.

In this plugin a background-image with repeat-x is used for the stars. So my question also is if it is possible to get just a percentage of a background-image with jQuery maybe or css and make specific styling to this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use the `background-size` css property

Answer (score 0):

Not really, by the looks of it. The plugin's not really set up in a 'hack-in-some-animation' friendly way.

I've given it a fair go, but it's a bit choppy. Hopefully its a starter for 10 though, and you can polish it up as desired. Check out the [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/rsoy837r/2/).

```
var delayPerStar = 500;
var div = $('#rating').parent('div');
var siblingDiv = $('#rating').siblings('div');
var content = div.data('content');
div.attr('data-content', '');
var i=0;

var fn = function(){
var cb = function(){
    div.attr('data-content', div.attr('data-content')+content[i]);
    if(div.attr('data-content').length<=$('#rating').val()){

    siblingDiv.css({
        fontSize: 50+((content.length-(i-1)*10))+'px'
    });
    div.css({
        fontSize: 50+((content.length-(i-1)*10))+'px'
    });
    }

    siblingDiv.css({
        width: (($('#rating').val() / (i+1))*100)+'%'
    });
    if(div.attr('data-content').length == content.length){
        return;
    }
    setTimeout(cb, delayPerStar);
    i++;
};
setTimeout(cb, delayPerStar);
};
fn();
```